# Como usar varios Condicionales "IF" en un Store Procedure en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Quisiera saber como puedo utilizar varios IF en un Store procedure en SQL Server,
como seria la Sintaxis? 
Aquí tengo un ejemplo de uno, pero este solo tiene un If y un Else y dentro de ese ELSE hay otras dos, pero necesito hacer mas y no me funciona...

```
DECLARE @Number int;  
SET @Number = 50;  
IF @Number > 100  
   PRINT 'The number is large.'  
ELSE   
  BEGIN  
  IF @Number < 10  
  PRINT 'The number is small.' 
ELSE  
   PRINT 'The number is medium.' 
END
```

Comment: Te refieres a If anidados? IF (condicion) BEGIN END ELSE IF (condicion) BEGIN END ELSE IF (condicion) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar lo que necesitas sólo debes encerrar en bloques BEGIN/END cada condición que necesites construir de la siguiente forma:

```
IF(Condición)
 BEGIN
  /*Código*/
 END
ELSE 
   IF(Condición)
      BEGIN
         /*Código*/ 
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
         /*Código*/
      END
```

Te dejo la **[documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** para que la revises

Comment: La indentación de ese último else, de verdad, me da escalofríos... :(

Comment: Tienes razón @jachguate.. no me había percatado... gracias por la observación =)

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (La condicion)
begin

(Si hay mas de una orden dentro del if escribir begin ... end)

end

Else if (segunda condicion)

begin 

end
```

y cuando acabes con los if

```
ELSE 

   BEGIN

   END
```